# How use vlookup (equivalent) like excel in Talend

Tags: excel, match, vlookup, talend

I have an input excel file structured as follows:

| id | name | Parentid | ParentName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 |  |  |
| 2 | Name2 |  | Name1 |
| 2 | Name3 |  | Name2 |

I want to retrieve the id of the parent name id in a new dedicated column ParentID.
The result I'm looking for:

| id | name | Parentid | ParentName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 |  |  |
| 2 | Name2 | 1 | Name1 |
| 3 | Name3 | 2 | Name2 |

In excel I would simply use in the Parentid cells : `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2;A$2:D$5;4;FALSE);"")` 
But I don't find how to achieve it in Talend, how should i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Read the source as main input and connect it with tMap component
2. Read the same source as lookup and connect it with tMap component
3. Apply the join condition on ParentName = Name in tMap
4. Connect the output from tMap to any output component to view results

For an example I have used tFixedFlowInput component instead of excel input.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks ! It works perfectly. 
But in my dataset some parentId are already fill in the column, how coud I trigger Tmap only if parentId is an empty cell ? 
I suppose I could use something like : `(row1.Id==Null)?row2.Id:row1.Id` but I don't find the correct formula.

Comment: try null instead of Null in your formula, it seems correct otherwise